# How do you compute the DC operating point (IC,VCE) and draw an AC equivalent circuit?

Tags: bjt

I just started learning about electronics and decided to quickly sketch a circuit. When it comes to OP and changing the said circuit into an Ac equivalent, I got stuck.
Sorry in advance if this is considered a basic question.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you put any voltages on to any nodes?

Comment: This diagram is all i have to work with

Comment: Right at the beginning. I am not really sure what to do since the source i was learning from is poorly done.

Comment: Do you know the Vbe of the transistor?

Comment: I'm sorry no. The site only provided the name of the transistor and told me to add it in a circuit.

Comment: As far as the DC operating point is concerned: Normally, it is not "computed" but SELECTED by you - and, as a second step, the circuit is designed accordingly.

Comment: Does it help if you make the assumption that the Vbe of the transistor is 0.7V?  And for the DC operating point all capacitors are replaced with open circuits?

Comment: Have you studied voltage dividers yet? Can you work out what voltage R2 and R3 put on the base of the transistor?

Comment: Sorry, but we have seen this circuit or at least a transistor biased with 4 resistors so many times in questions from people who seem to try nothing by themselves that probably you will not get a full tutorial written specifically for you. You can think to start to begin to consider if you possibly could try to work the case by yourself for example by applying this https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_2.html or some other of the numerous tutorials in the web.

Comment: Thank you I will try to use that.

Answer (score 2):

For the DC analysis, remove all capacitors (they act as open-circuit devices at DC) and calculate the DC emitter current (Ie), with which you calculate r_e=vt/Ie.

For the AC analysis, short all capacitors (if you're thinking of ideal analysis for very large frequencies), calculate r_pi by r_pi=r_e(Beta+1) and then draw the common emitter ac equivalent model, which is likely the one you'll be using in your analysis.

Comment: Understanding this needs so much knowledge that with it the whole question would be never born. The questioner can see us quite conceited.

Comment: I think that this answer is correct **however** pretty useless to OP. What OP needs to learn is **circuit analysis** followed up by **small signal analysis**. There are many, many books and courses explaining this, OP needs to study these.