# I need help with probably a simple problem

Tags: amplifier

I am taking an online course on electronic devices. It is poorly done and I already paid for it.

Yesterday I asked a question similar to this one however I didn't understand the explanation. This time I took a problem from the course, and I hope somebody is willing to explain me in details what to do.

[image]

Comment: hi! Could you please make your title describe the technical problem, instead just saying "Help?!" :) Thank you!

Comment: If you don't understand an answer you've gotten on here before, you shouldn't be asking a similar question again. Instead, use the comment function under that answer to ask for clarification.

Comment: And you addressed only very few of the comments you've got under your previous question. So, no wonder you haven't gotten any better responses. Answering a question so that you understand it takes more effort on your side, too, than just dropping us a circuit diagram.

Comment: Vote to close: Duplicate of your own: [How do you compute the DC operating point (IC,VCE) and draw an AC equivalent circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519640/how-do-you-compute-the-dc-operating-point-ic-vce-and-draw-an-ac-equivalent-cir)  (not in schematics, but in the problems in understanding you face)

Comment: I am sorry if this angered you in some way. I didn't address all the questions because i couldn't understand them. I thought that by posting the question again i would have a higher chance of help. Sorry if this is not how this community works i'm new here too.

Comment: Your questions have a better chance here if you improve them instead of re-asking them.  This isn't (quite) a duplicate question since it is about a different type of amplifier.  Viewed narrowly, though, it could be taken as a duplicate since the concepts needed are the same.

Comment: In your place, I'd go back and fix the original question since this one seems to be on the way to being closed.

Comment: So you're basically asking one of us to do (for free) what the course (for which you're paying) should have done? Asking **again** doesn't get you any points here. You have to show that you did **all you can** to help yourself. There are plenty of books that explain what you're asking.

Comment: @StevePittman:  Start with one concept - say, the operating point.  Give **your** understanding of what it is and how you would calculate it - and what information you would need to do so.  Explain what you are given from the course.  Show how you have tried to apply your understanding to the question and information you were given.  Explain where you get stuck.

Comment: If the information given in the course is inadequate, look things up on your own.  Your course is on the internet - and so are a **lot** of other sources of information.

Comment: The [wikipedia page on BJT biasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_transistor_biasing) is a starting place for more information if your online course is completely inadequate.

Comment: @StevePittman:  I don't think you've actually angered anyone.  Miffed, sure.  Exasperated, certainly.  Angered, unlikely.